# Courcelle's Theorem: Looking for papers

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, parameterized-complexity

I am looking for an easy and introductory paper on the proof of [Courcelle's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courcelle%27s_theorem). I am also interested in its connection to [parameterized complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) regarding the [treewidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth).

I am only a beginner in this field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a soft introduction in Rolf Niedermeier's book [Invitation to Fixed Parameter Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198566077). Daniel Marx also has quite a few slides available on his [homepage](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/) that contain short examples of modeling a problem in MSOL. One set of relevant slides is [here](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/marx-adfocs-2013.pdf). For more links, see a [related question on CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17739/5693).

Answer (score 4):

Courcelle's Theorem is one of the things that is better explained (compared with Niedermeier's book)  in the book of [Flum and Grohe](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-29953-X) (see the treewidth chapter), since model checking problems etc. are covered in detail there. By the same authors and Frick there is also a generalization of Courcelle's Theorem: [Query evaluation via tree-decompositions](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=602222). You might also look at similar meta theorems for [clique-width](http://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Textes1/BC-Makowsky-Rotics%282000%29.pdf) and [shrub-depth](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~hlineny/plain/papers/shrub-mfcs-withapp.pdf).

Also look [here](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0017376.pdf) for a short overview of some of Courcelle's earlier papers.